# Cisco ASA 5505 access external IP address from internal

Tags: cisco, routing, ip, cisco-asa

Got a bit of a head scratcher.

ASA Version: 8.3(1)
ASDM Version: 6.3(1)

So I have an ASA 5505 with 3 interfaces (Inside, outside and Hosting). The inside interface has the IP range of 10.0.0.X and the hosting interface has the IP range 10.0.1.X. Both ranges run on separate external IP addresses (inside is 80.71.2.81 and hosting is 80.71.2.82).

The problem I am having is accessing the external IP address of the hosting range when on the inside interface.

I have looked at hair pinning, but I am not sure this will work as I have disabled access between the internal interfaces.

Please let me know if you need any more information

Comment: I would suggest using DNS redirection for this.

Comment: Ok, how would I go about setting that up?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/555272/126632