# Cisco ASA 5505: Reach outside DNS address from inside

Tags: domain-name-system, cisco, cisco-asa

We use a Cisco ASA 5505 at our company. We have a dns A record (home.company.com) pointing to the external IP. In the ASA 5505 the http-port (80) is forwarded to an inside web server.

No problem reaching http://home.company.com from the internet, but how do we get it to work inside the ASA 5505? It doesn't work and we need to use the internal IP to reach the web server. What we want is to be able to reach http://home.company.com from inside the LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question never was accepted, it can't be marked as a duplicate.  But the answer to your question is found here: [Cisco ASA 5520 Unable to access external IP on Internal Network](https://serverfault.com/questions/487274/cisco-asa-5520-unable-to-access-external-ip-on-internal-network)

You are talking about Hairpin NAT.

Personally, I don't recommend configuring an ASA this way, and think it is smarter to have your internal DNS servers point the DNS FQDN to the actual internal IP of the server itself, thus never traversing the firewall and adding extra I/O to it for no reason.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Solve it with internal DNS. Create a new zone home.company.com create an emty a record (no name) and add ip of the internal web server you want to reach. Users from inside get internal dns with internal ip and external dns as before. This solution makes assumption that you have your own internal DNS server.